# Add array to cookie codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

I am using code igniter. I have to make cart feature and I have to save product ids to cookie but I am not able to add array to cookie. My controller code to add cookie is

```
public function add_to_cart(){
    $product_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $cookie= array(
       'name'   => 'cookie_product',
       'value'  => $product_id,
       'expire' => '3600',
   );
   $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
   var_dump($this->input->cookie('cookie_product',true));die;

}
```

`$product_id` has my product id for example 41 . need help !

Comment: for cart why dont you use default cart library of CI

Comment: I did not knew about that

Comment: use CI cart library it has all required functionality

Comment: thank you the cart library has done my work thanks for helping @prasannaputtaswamy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use cookies directly. Use cart library which will handle cookies for you.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html

```
$this->load->library('cart');


$data = array(
    'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
    'qty'     => 1,
    'price'   => 39.95,
    'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
    'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
);

$this->cart->insert($data);
```

And to view items

```
<?php print_r($this->cart->contents()); ?>
```

Comment: @AmmarKhan - cool please consider to accept answer if worked.

Answer (score 0):

Cart sounds like a good solution.

The reason why your original code wasn't working is you were trying to pass an array instead of breaking it into individual parameters.

If you did want to fix it, your code should be:

`$this->input->set_cookie($cookie['name'], $cookie['value'], $cookie['expire']);`

Incidentally, you can store an array in a cookie by using serialize and unserialize to store the cookie as a string instead of an array:

`$this->input->set_cookie('cookie_product', serialize($cookie));
var_dump(unserialize($this->input->cookie('cookie_product',true)));`